# Close a Websocket on application window close for a Chrome application

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome application launched in a browser window the utilizes web sockets. The application binds to `localhost:9999`. All this works fine until I close the application window and reopen. Chrome is still holding onto that port and comes up with an error.

I would like to be able to close the web socket / unbind the port when the window is closed so that when reopened it establishes the connection again.

I have tried the `chrome.app.window.onClosed` in the `background.js` file to no avail. It doesn't seem to get called when the window is closed. I don't know it this is because I have to some how tell it which window to look out for.

Comment: The same issue is addressed here - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromedeveditor/issues/1023

Answer (score 2):

After creating the window for your app you can attach an OnClosed listener.
See also https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onClosed

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    chrome.app.window.create(
      'index.html',
      { id: 'win'},
      function(createdWindow) {
        function mainWindowClosed () {
          websocket.close();
        }
        mainWindow = createdWindow;
        mainWindow.onClosed.addListener(mainWindowClosed);
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problems. `onClosed` listener didn't work. A work around is when you launch your app and create a socket first check whether it is available or not before creating and binding to it.

Use `chrome.sockets.udp.getSockets()` that returns an array of open `sockets(sock_arr)`. Now look for localPort in a *for* loop i.e `sock_arr[i].localPort == 9999` and close the socket if any found. Then proceed with socket creation and binding.

Comment: Hi! Sorry to take so long getting back to you. I still have this issue and I'm interested in your workaround. Would I implement this in the background.js?